# IF statement doesnt compare values recieved from file

Tags: python, file

I just started programming a few days ago. I made this program where the user can create a quiz ( all the Q's and A's are written to a file ) When i come to read the  answers file, i make a with statement to extract every line independently, then compare it with every independent line of the Qs file. This works just fine, and the value that i want to be compared is indeed. But when the answer actually matches the one on the file, the if statement still returns the else commands! Its unbelievable! Here's the output for clarification.

> Question Number  1  : Whats your name
>
> input the Answer :abdo
>
> Sorry, thats Wrong! The right answer is : abdo
>
> Your score is : 0
>
> Question Number  2  : whats my name
>
> input the Answer :abdo1
>
> Sorry, thats Wrong! The right answer is :abdo1
>
> Your score is : 0

This is my code:

```
import sys
questions = []
answers = []
score = 0
print("+++++++++++++++Welcome to SS Quiz Maker++++++++++++++++")
save = input("Would you like to create a new quiz or load your saved one :")
if save == "y":
    for i in range(0,2):
        print( "Question number",i + 1)
        questions.append(input("Enter a Question :"))
        answers.append(input("Enter an Answer :"))

    f = open("SS_QUIZ_QUESTIONS.txt", "w")
    f.truncate()
    for i in questions:
        f.write(i)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
    f = open("SS_QUIZ_ANSWERS.txt", "w")
    for i in answers:
        f.write(i)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
else:   
    for i in range(0,2):
        with open('SS_QUIZ_QUESTIONS.txt') as f:
            u = 1
            for line in f:
                if u == i + 1:
                    break
        with open('SS_QUIZ_ANSWERS.txt') as f:
            u = 1
            for line2 in f:
                if u == i + 1:
                    break
        print("Question Number ",i + 1," :",line)
        ans = str(input("input the Answer :" ))

        if  ans == line2:
            print("Correct")
            score = score +1
            print("Your score is :",score)

        else:
            print("Sorry, thats Wrong!")
            print("The right answer is :", line2)
            print("Your score is :",score)
```

Comment: is there whitespace? can you print the two lines out side by side?

Comment: what do you mean by whitespace

Comment: sorry don't no much about python so please be patient with me

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAttia It's not about Python. Whitespace is characters like space, newline, tab. Two strings can look the same when you print them, but they might have differences in spaces. `"foo"` versus `"foo "`

Comment: Your project does not seem to be suitable for someone who just started learning programming.

Comment: try `print(repr(ans)+' '+repr(line2))` and make sure they are the same

Comment: no i cant do that, or atleast dont know how. Why?

Comment: Ok quick edit:  I've been learning python for 8 months. started this program 3 days ago

Comment: depperm when i tried that the output was:

Comment: 'abdo' 'abdo\n'

Comment: notice that `line2` has newline character. Look at @LeonZ answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you write the answers to your file, you also write the newline character `"\n"`. Now, when you compare your strings, you are actually comparing `abdo1` to `abdo1\n`, which is false. Use the `.rstrip()` method on your `line2` string before comparing.

In your code:

```
if ans == line2.rstrip():
```

Should do the trick

Comment: great thanks to Leon Z and depperm. Works like a charm!